# Screen resolution is not automatically changed when login

Tags: 18.04, xorg, hdmi, display-resolution

On Ubuntu 18.04, my `.xprofile` reads

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_50"  188.75  2560 2712 2976 3392  1080 1083 1093 1114 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "2560x1080_50"
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "2560x1080_50"
```

However, when I login, the resolution is the same. I had to go to terminal and type

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "2560x1080_50"
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "2560x1080_50"
```

Which means the mode is created. Somehow the later commands are not run.

I am using Intel HD 4000, if it helps.

Could any of you kindly help? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to change the background from picture to color and it works. Seems like a bug from Ubuntu.